# iPhone dev: Recurse all project resoureces and collect paths

Tags: iphone, cocoa, resources, path

I have a bunch of HTML resources in my app organized in a hierarchy like so:

```
dirA
|---> index.html
|---> a1.html
|---> a2.html
|---> dirB
      |---> b1.html
      |---> b2.html
|---> dirC
      |---> c5.html
      |---> c19.html
```

I'm trying to collect the absolute paths of all HTML resources however deep down, but can't seem to figure out how. So far I've tried:

`NSArray myPaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];`

This returns an empty array, because I have no HTML files at the root of my project. Then there is:

`NSArray myPaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"html" inDirectory:@"dirA"];`

This returns an array containing only the paths for the three HTML resources directly below dirA. If I read the doc correctly, I guess this is to be expected; `pathsForResourcesOfType` does not traverse subdirectories. But is there a (preferably nice) way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`NSDirectoryEnumerator`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to iterate everything, then just check if the string's [`pathExtension`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-pathExtension) is "html".  If it is, you've found one.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];